# How to download BASH on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, bash

Currently, I am learning to use "BASH" and I don't know how to download it on my pc. 
So it would be appreciated if someone lets me know how to download it on WINDOWS 8.1.

Comment: try this one [Link1](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/), may be it works. 
or follow this steps [Link 2](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 5):

You have basically two choices.

1. Install Git for Windows. Git comes with its own bash.
2. Install the Windows Ubuntu sub system.

I prefer the Git bash approach because this also knows other Windows installed applications. The Ubuntu sub system acts more separated.

Have fun.

Comment: Bash on Windows is not available for windows 8.1 (only windows 10) and likely never will be. Another alternative would be cygwin, with works more like the bash subsystem rather than git-bash